# How intelligent are unix utilities?

Tags: text-processing, grep, sort, coreutils

Unix utilities like sort, find, grep, diff et al are very handy to perform quick tasks, sometimes without writing any code at all.

I wanted to know what algorithms do they internally use and how do intelligently decide a specific algorithm for a specific task? For example if sort gets a huge input file, will it use different algorithms for different data sizes?

Does grep intelligently switch algorithms while searching different data sets?

Comment: They are so intelligent they will one day take over the Earth. But for now you have to decide which ones you are going to use, such as `grep`, `egrep`, or `fgrep`.

Comment: But if you use egrep regularly and then suddenly switch to  fgrep, it might decide to kill you in your sleep for being unfaithful.

Comment: They are as intelligent as the hands that wield them.

Answer (score 7):

Unix is just a standard, it specifies what the implementations should do, but not how they should do it.

Therefore implementations of grep/sort/find will most likely use different approaches on different systems (and even one system, like Linux, there are concurrent implementations).

For Linux, you can always look into the source code.

Comment: To complete your answer: http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/

Comment: Why would you need to look at the source code? greps algorithms are well known and documented. It's even in the Wikipedia page for grep. [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grep)

Comment: @Deleted I think that you are mistaking principles with implementation.

Comment: @Let_Me_Be: The algorithm and even the implementation is well known and documented. [link](http://www.grouse.com.au/ggrep/string.html) [link](http://lists.freebsd.org/pipermail/freebsd-current/2010-August/019362.html)

Comment: @Deleted Maybe I don't understand what you are trying to say, but that Linux grep from coreutils is using a specific algorithm, doesn't mean that all implementations use this algorithm. And yes, you are correct in that algorithms tend to be well known (since that's the point of designing them).

Comment: @Let_Me_Be: Any Linux distro I've ever worked with uses GNU grep. The algorithms and how they're implemented in GNU grep are well known. The information is readily available in the links I posted in my previous comments.  I just feel it would be more beneficial to the OP to either explain how it works or point out where to find that information online rather than just saying, "look into the source code". Telling the OP to go read the source code doesn't really provide an answer to the question.

Comment: @Deleted OK, then you probably just need to reformulate your comments, because your motive is hard to follow. And don't forget that this is Unix & Linux not just Linux.

Answer (score 2):

You may be interested in this [mailing list post](http://lists.freebsd.org/pipermail/freebsd-current/2010-August/019310.html) by the original GNU grep author which explains a few of the GNU grep optimizations. Another [enjoyable exploration](http://ridiculousfish.com/blog/archives/2006/05/30/old-age-and-treachery/) by ridiculous_fish (author of Hex Fiend)

Answer (score 1):

The UNIX standard doesn't specify implementation details for the standard system tools, except for really rare cases. You can find the latest Single Unix Specification vesion [here](http://www.unix.org/single_unix_specification/)(warning: registration required).

With that in mind, every UNIX(System V and direct descendants like BSD, Solaris, Mac OS X, etc..) or UNIX based Operating System (far descendants or alikes: Linux, Minix) has its own implementations of the utilities described in the UNIX specification. For eg. take a look at [FreeBSD's](http://svn.freebsd.org/viewvc/base/head/usr.bin/) and [Linux/GNU Coreutils](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/coreutils.git/tree/src). Beware that some tools are separate whole project by themselves like [GNU diff](http://www.gnu.org/software/diffutils/) or [GNU grep](http://www.gnu.org/software/grep/). Also another fact is that some implementations of these tools might find their way into other UNIX like systems as standard then the ones they were initially written for, for e.g. [some gnu coreutils in freebsd](http://svn.freebsd.org/viewvc/base/head/gnu/usr.bin/) or GCC.

Bonus: To wrap your head around the UNIX family tree, take a look at [this graph](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/d9/Unix_history-simple.en.svg).

Answer (score 0):

> I wanted to know what algorithms do
>   they internally use and how do
>   intelligently decide a specific
>   algorithm for a specific task? For
>   example if sort gets a huge input
>   file, will it use different algorithms
>   for different data sizes?

That is an interesting question (+1 for that). I have no clue as to what the answer is, but if I were you, I'd look at the source code of typical GNU utilities to get an idea of their algorithms.

> Does grep intelligently switch algorithms while searching different data sets?

I don't think so. Don't quote me since I cannot really tell you with 100% certainty, but I really don't think so. The UNIX philosophy of things is that one thing does one thing and one thing only. That's why we have several versions of grep (`grep`, `egrep`, `fgrep`).

Also, the idea is to do one thing and only one thing at run-time. Different behavior and algorithms can be configured as command-line arguments, so that the same program can act slightly differently (and possibly slightly more optimized) between runs. Good examples are the `wc` and `diff` command.

However, the behavioral adaptation is configuration-based (via cmd line arguments); they don't change/adapt behavior at run-time. It  is typically an unnecessary complexity for the type of artifacts the UNIX tools aim to be.

Such complexity is more appropriate of more complex, less general purpose tools IMO.

Comment: The theme here is more of *No, they are actually dumb!*. You have to tell them exactly what the must do. Anyways, we don't want them be too smart on us you know.

Answer (score 0):

> Does grep intelligently switch algorithms while searching different data sets?

I don't think so, but it does switch to the "fast" non-RE algorithm when given the -f flag (or invoked as fgrep).

Comment: i.e. not really intelligent :)